Conditional Output with user input
I am trying to write a form in Latex where I'm asking a question an if the answer is no I whant to ask another question. I'm a real beginner in Latex and I need a little help how to start it.
It should look like this in the form:
Do you thing the size of the team is reasonable?
\Choicemenu with yes or no
If the answer is yes -> skip the next question
If the answer is no ->
What size would you prefer?
\Choicemenu with 1,3,4
Thanks for you help and I'm sorry if this is a trivial question. But I have no clue how to start here except from the package \ifthen. But I don't know how to start.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You want to look at hyperref. But ... this is not something you want to try if you are new to LaTeX imho. Forms support is patchy in my experience and it is made worse by the fact that you can't easily predict what different PDF viewers will do. So it is hard to tell if you're doing something wrong, hyperref is doing something wrong or the PDF is fine but your PDF viewer is doing something wrong. You don't want this as your first experience of LaTeX.

Note that you cannot change the PDF on the basis of a user response to a question. You could, I think, have  it jump to the appropriate question. But this is unlikely to work properly in all PDF viewers, so unless you know what people are using, you are going to have issues. I'm not sure whether choice menus work properly in all viewers, for example. Certainly radio buttons etc. do not.

it isn't clear where you want the interaction to happen. You could interactively ask questions while running latex, but most people these days run tex in the background from their editor so interaction is not possible. Alternatively you could in theory generate a pdf with interactive form implemented but not all pdf viewers support that.
